# How many people were at a party determined by the number of handshakes

Tags: combinatorics

At a party, everyone shook hands with everybody else. There were $66$ handshakes. How many people were at the party?

[image]

I saw this question as pretty straightforward, but when I checked the solutions, it said the answer was $12$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The number of handshakes $\binom n2$

Comment: Rather focus on the way I did it and not an alternative method please.

Comment: Also observe that there will be no handshakes if the number person is $1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got your line $1=\frac12+b+c$, from the case of $n=1$ people; but in that case there would be $0$ hand shakes.  In the case of $2$ people there will be $1$ handshake.

Comment: Thank you, I never saw that.

Answer (score 1):

If there are $n$ persons who shake hands with each other,

the first person will shake hand with $n-1$ persons

the next person will shake hand with the rest $n-2$ persons

and so on

So, the number of handshakes will be $n-1+n-2+\cdots+1=\dfrac{n(n-1)}2$